# How do I grab data from a table whose content is grabbed from a back-end function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, database, backend

Basically what I need to do is take data from one table that slow-loads its rows(data) from a back-end function call(ASP.NET). It populates the table with dimensions, where one row contains the dimension name, database connection, checkbox that indicates whether its assigned or not, a key field and name field. My task is that I should take all dimensions that are assigned(have the assigned checkbox checked) and put them into a new table with just assigned dimensions. What I dont know is how to properly do it, I tried with plain javascript and jQuery but every time it throws and error saying that the ''jActual variable is not defined''. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I dont know if I can show any code since its work related.

Answer (score 0):

Well, just drop a gridview into the page like this:

```
    <div style="width:40%"> 
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True" DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover">
    </asp:GridView>
    </div>
```

Now, the code to load the above grid? You can use this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If IsPostBack = False Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub

Sub LoadGrid()

    Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand("SELECT top 15 FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City, Active from tblHotels",
                    New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST3))
        cmdSQL.Connection.Open()
        GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End Using

 End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

So, as you can see, we use a "call" to our routine "LoadGrid".

We are free to use/have/get ANY number of columns - and note how the true/false even renders as a check box for you.

So, as a general rule you want to use a GridView, or even perhaps a listView.

Thus the rendering of 3 or 20 columns is done automatics for you.